# Ola Money Integration Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Am new to Ola money integration. I am following http://docs.olamoney.com/docs/integration-guide-ios

In this, From where I will get OlaCabs proxy app. I did not found any SDK which will have the class OMMerchantInfo
I am blocked with this step. Is there any SDK or framework is available to use this provided class. ?

```
OMMerchantInfo *merchantInfo = [[OMMerchantInfo alloc] initWithMerchantAcessToken:@"ola_access_token"
notifiyUrl:@"mynotify_url.php"
returnUrl:@"dummy_return.jsp"
currencyType:@"INR"                  
enviornmentType:UserEnviornmentStage];
[OMOlaMoneyClient setMerchantInfo:merchantInfo];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean you don't know where to download the sdk?

Comment: Unbelievable!  Objective C repo is not available I checked with account https://github.com/olamoney?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query= also. Sent query to support@olamoney.com

Comment: Exatly @SeanChense

Comment: also there is a point > Download OlaCabs proxy app from where i will download this. ?